# Find all tagged strings in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I have an app where tagging users using the is done with Javascript like `@abc  @def  @xyz`

That's obviously mixed in other text which is passed to backend in PHP. I'd like to find all tagged users `( abc , def, xyz, . . . )`. Pointers?

```
preg_match_all('/@(.*?) /', $file, $match);
```

brings all the tags ending with an empty space, but what about `'@abc,'` or `'@abc:'`, or `'@abc*'`

So simple and yet... Pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Anchor against the word boundary flag (`\b`) rather than an empty space.

```
preg_match_all('/@(.*?)\b/', $file, $match);
```

Comment: `/(^|\s)(@\w+)/`  did  the magic

Comment: You're welcome? And that's not a reliable way to do it.